# Print parameter or variable depending on a file's path only once

Tags: xslt

Sorry in advance if the title is too vague.

I have to process several XML files referenced by each other with XSLT and search for certain errors.

My XMLs typically look like this:

```
<topic>
    ... some elements ...
    <topicref @href="path-to-another-file"/>
    ... some other elements ...
    <figure> ... </figure>
</topic>
```

And my desired output is:

```
path-to-a-file:
    Errors found

path-to-another-file:
    Other errors found
```

I get the paths from href attributes and I'd like to print a path if there's an error in the corresponding file.

The important parts of my XSLT:

```
<!-- ingress referenced files -->
<xsl:template match="//*[@href]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="@href"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[@href]">
    </xsl:apply-templates>            
</xsl:template>

<!-- matching topic elements to check -->
<xsl:template match="topic">
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:if test=".//figure">
        <!-- Right now this is where I print the path of the current file -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="figure">
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$path"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- check if there's any error -->
<xsl:template match="figure">
    <xsl:param name="path"/>

    <xsl:if test="...">
        <xsl:call-template name="printError">
            <xsl:with-param name="errorText" select="'...'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="filePath" select="..."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="elementId" select="..."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>  
    <xsl:if test="...">
        <xsl:call-template name="printError">
            <xsl:with-param name="errorText" select="'...'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="filePath" select="..."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="elementId" select="..."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- print error message -->
<xsl:template name="printError">
    <xsl:param name="errorText"/>
    <xsl:param name="filePath"/>
    <xsl:param name="elementId"/>

    ... print out some stuff ...

</xsl:template>
```

Where should I print out the path of a file? With this transformation I always write it out if the file has a figure element even when it doesn't contain any mistakes. 
Like this:

```
path-to-a-file:
    Errors found

path-to-file-with-no-errors:

path-to-another-file:
    Other errors found
```

If I put the part in question elsewhere (i.e. in the error checking or printing template) it gets printed after every figure elements examined or errors printed.

I assume the problem could be solved with variables but I'm new to XSLT so I'm not sure how to go about it.

EDIT:

I need to display the path of the file when I find an error in it but only once, after the first error was found. 
Errors can be found only in files with figure elements.

I hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: After reading your question, still not understood what do you want to do?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope the problem is clear this way.

Comment: <!-- Right now this is where I print the path of the current file --> is the place where you're printing file path, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not what I need. This way the path gets printed out even when the file does not contain errors (I pointed this out in my post).

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the current element matches a previous element in the XML, using something like:

```
<variable name='currentlocation' select="@href"/>
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::topicref[contains(@href, $currentlocation)])">

 (process this only if there is no preceding sibling with the same @href as the current location)
```

edit: this test would solve only half the problem. You need another test to check if there is an error in the other file.